# How to accurately determine that your web app is "standalone" vs browser window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I have created my web app in standalone version, so that when users add it to homescreen it looks like normal app rather than a webpage.

That made styling a little more difficult as now, I have to think about the "notch" in mobile phones and I need to have conditional styles because of that.

I am using tailwind and for most of my components I simply added styles just like this:

```
  <div className="standalone:pt-12">
```

And everything works.

However, I've had some issues with `React-Hot-Toast` library, where the conditional style some times applied some times didn't.

Here is my logic:

```
_app.tsx

  const isStandalone =
    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen h-full standalone:pt-12">
      <Toaster
        containerStyle={{ top: isStandalone ? '54px' : '8px' }}
      />
```

It seems like `isStandalone` variable doesn't always set, am I doing anything wrong?

If I simply do:

```
        containerStyle={{ top:'54px' }}
```

it works, but whenever I use that variable I see issues, is there a better method to determine if app is in "standalone" mode?